# ¿Como hacer para crear una pagina nueva con un formato ya establecido en FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Tengo una aplicación ya elaborada en la cual uno de sus módulos es generar reportes en PDF, el reporte se genera excelente, el detalle es que necesito que cada 20 registros se genere una nueva pagina de este reporte pero esta se genera en blanco y no debe ser así ¿Como puedo hacer para que esta nueva pagina ya tenga su encabezado y estructura como la pagina anterior del documento? Soy estudiante de informática y pues estoy adquiriendo conocimientos, agradeceré su ayuda por favor. La librería que estoy usando es **FPDF** este es el cdigo:

```
<?php

require "pdf/fpdf.php";

class PDF extends FPDF
{
}


//declaramos la hoja

$pdf= new PDF ('L','mm',array(500, 500));
$pdf->SetMargins(10,5);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(2);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,155);
$pdf->AddPage();


//Datos del titulo


$pdf->SetTextColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 9);
$pdf->Image('logo.png' , 390,20, 35 , 38,'png','');
$pdf->Cell(0, 20, '', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'REPUBLICA BOLIVARIANA DE VENEZUELA', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'AGENCIA AUTOMOTRIZ ALLCARS', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->ln();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 12);
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'INVENTARIO FISICO', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'AUTOS:', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'FECHA:', 0, 1, 'C');


//Datos de conexion

mysql_connect("localhost", "USER", "PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("BASE_DE_DATOS");

//FIN DE DATOS DE CONEXION

$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla";
$rec= mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rec))
{
$pdf->Cell(0,5, $row['fecha'], 0, 0, 'C');
}

$pdf->ln();

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFontSize(8);

$pdf->SetTextColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 8);
$pdf->Cell(265, 5, '1.- CLIENTE:', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Cell(40, 5, 'CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(120, 5, 'APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, 'DIRECCION', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(85, 5, 'CEDULA', 1, 0, 'C');


$pdf->SetFontSize(9);

$sql="SELECT * FROM encabezado";
$rec= mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rec))
{
$pdf->Cell(80, 10, $row['direccion_li'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['cod_ut'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $row['division'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, '', 0, 0, 'C');
}



**//
// AQUI NECESITO QUE SIGA CON EL FORMATO YA ESTABLECIDO EN UNA NUEVA HOJA**
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFontSize(9);

$sql="SELECT * FROM encabezado";
$rec= mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rec))
{

$pdf->Cell(40, 5, $row['ced'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(120, 5, $row['nombres'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, $row['codigo'], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(85, 5, $row['uep'], 1, 0, 'C');


}
**//
// HASTA AQUI**




$pdf->Ln();


$pdf->SetFontSize(9);
$pdf->Cell(170, 5, 'DIRECTOR', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(170, 5, 'CLIENTE', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(170, 5, 'FIRMA', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(170, 5, 'FIRMA', 0, 0, 'C');


$pdf->Output(/*$Archivo, $tipo_output*/);
//$pdf->Output("Contrato_".$per_Rut."-".$per_DV.".pdf", "D");
?>
```

en la parte que especifique como comentario es la que me muestra la lista de los datos almacenados en la base de datos anteriormente, lo que necesito es que cada vez que se genere una nueva pagina, el formato como (logo, encabezado, fecha, firmas inferiores, etc) ya aparezca, solo me siga mostrando resultados del listado si es que los hay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public function LineItems() {
        $datos = $this->listaItemsDetalle(); 
        $header = array("REPUBLICA BOLIVARIANA DE VENEZUELA", "AGENCIA AUTOMOTRIZ","INVENTARIO FISICO","CANT.", "AUTOS");
        $this->SetDataFont();
        $this->AddPage();
        $w = array(10, 40,90, 15, 20);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++) {
        $this->SetFillColor(192,192,192);
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetFontSize(10);
        $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'L','true');
    }

    $this->Ln();
    $x = $this->GetX();
    $y = $this->GetY();
    $i = 0;
    //////////////la razon indica cuantos items seran visibles en cada hoja.
    $razon=30;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($datos)) {
        //print_r('<pre>');
        //print_r($row);
        $data[] = array(++$i, $row[5],$row[4], $row[2], $row[3]);
    }

    if (!isset($data)) {
        $data[] = null;
     }else{
        $j=$i;
        foreach($data as $row)
        {   
            if($i>=($j+$razon)){
                $this->AddPage();
                $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 3);
                $this->setTextFont(true);
                $header = array("REPUBLICA BOLIVARIANA DE VENEZUELA", "AGENCIA AUTOMOTRIZ","INVENTARIO FISICO","CANT.", "AUTOS");
                //$this->SetDataFont();
                $this->setTextFont(false);
                $this->SetDataFont();
                $w = array(10, 40, 90,  15, 20);

                for($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++) {
                $this->SetFillColor(192,192,192);
                $this->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
                $this->SetFontSize(10);
                $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'L','true');
            }

            $this->Ln();
            $j=$i;
            }
                $this->SetFontSize(8);
                $this->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
                $y1 = $this->GetY();

                $this->MultiCell($w[0], 6, $row[0], 'R');
                $y2 = $this->GetY();
                $yH = $y2 - $y1;

                $this->SetXY($x + $w[0], $this->GetY() - $yH);

                $this->Cell($w[1],$yH,$row[1],0, 0, 'L');
                $this->Cell($w[2],$yH,$row[2],0, 0, 'L');
                $this->Cell($w[3],$yH,$row[3],0, 0, 'R');
                $this->Cell($w[4],$yH,$row[4],0, 0, 'L');
                //$this->Cell($w[5],$yH,$row[5],'LRB', 0, 'C');

            $this->Ln();
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $this->Ln(10);

}
```

Lo importante es el valor de `$razon`, cada vez que muestre 30 lineas creara una nueva pagina y recargara lo que esta en el `header` (que en tu caso seria la cabecera que deseas mostrar), disculpa pero no tuve mucho tiempo para hacerlo sobre el tuyo. espero te sirva el ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo adapte a mis requerimientos y me ha servido a la perfección

Comment: @AntoJ, pues vota la respuesta y ciérrala para que todo siga su curso.